# In a ODEINT + THRUST observer, receiving error that expression must be a modifiable lvalue

Tags: c++, thrust, odeint

I have been working on extending / modifying the thrust + odeint example [[code](https://github.com/boostorg/odeint/blob/master/examples/thrust/lorenz_parameters.cu),[documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/numeric/odeint/doc/html/boost_numeric_odeint/tutorial/using_cuda__or_openmp__tbb_______via_thrust.html#boost_numeric_odeint.tutorial.using_cuda__or_openmp__tbb_______via_thrust.phase_oscillator_ensemble)] that varies systematically a parameter, and observes the effects.

I am having a strange error, where when I try to modify certain variables that should be modifiable, (and are modified in the example), I get the following error.

```
main.cu: error: expression must be a modifiable lvalue
```

Below is the source code for the observer struct that I am trying to run, with a comment showing the line that causes the error.

I understand this error to mean that the expression to the left of the assignment operator, `=`, is not a modifiable value. But it looks exactly the same to me as the variable with the same name in the example source above (which runs fine).

```
//// Observes the system to detect if it ever dies during the trial
struct death_observer {

  // CONSTRUCTOR
  death_observer( size_t N, size_t historyBufferLen = 1) 
    : m_N( N ), m_count( 0 ) { }

  template< class State , class Deriv >
  void operator()(State &x , Deriv &dxdt , value_type t ) const
  {
    ++m_count;                                 // <-- This line causes the error.
  }

  // variables
  size_t m_N;   
  size_t m_count;
};
```

... and here is the code from main() that runs the integrator and this observer, in case that is helpful.

```
  parallel_initial_condition_problem init_con_solver( N_ICS );
  death_observer obs( N_ICS );

  //////////////////////////////// // // integrate   
  typedef runge_kutta_dopri5< state_type , value_type , state_type , value_type, thrust_algebra, thrust_operations > stepper_type;
  const value_type abs_err = 1.0e-6;
  const value_type rel_err = 1.0e-6;

  double t = t_0;
  while( t < t_final ) {
    integrate_adaptive( make_controlled( abs_err, rel_err, stepper_type() ) ,
            init_con_solver ,
            std::make_pair( x.begin() , x.begin() + N_VARS*N_ICS  ),
            t , t + 1.0 , init_dt );
    t += 1.0;
    obs( x, *(&x+N_VARS*N_ICS), t); // not sure about middle arg here, but I don't think it is the cause of the error.
  }
```

I have tried to pare down my code to the most simple case.  Commenting out the 3rd to last line above causes the program to run fine.

What on earth am I doing wrong? What is different between my m_count and the m_count in the example code linked to above? Many thanks!

Comment: You declared your `operator ()` `const` and yet you attempt to modify a class data member inside it. Also, `*(&x+N_VARS*N_ICS)` is almost certainly not what you want, since `x` looks like a container from your `.begin()` calls.

Comment: Thank you. The `const` keyword was indeed the cause of my problem. I am now trying to figure out what I should put instead of `*(&x+N_VARS*N_ICS)`. If I do x.begin()+N_VARS*N_ICS, I get an error that it is the wrong type, but I want the 2nd argument to refer to a later point in x... Anyway, thank you!

Comment: Why did you supply this as a comment instead of an answer? If you add an answer, I'll select it as the answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting comment into an answer:

```
template< class State , class Deriv >
void operator()(State &x , Deriv &dxdt , value_type t ) const
{
    ++m_count;                                 // <-- This line causes the error.
}
```

You declared `operator()` as a `const` member function, and therefore it cannot modify class data members unless the member is declared as `mutable`.

Side note: `*(&x+N_VARS*N_ICS)` is almost certainly not correct, as `x` looks like a container from the `.begin()` calls.